# How to check if user has previously authenticated in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

Can I know if a user was previously authenticated in Django?

Quick list of expected results:

- User is currently logged in: return `true`
- User was logged in at once but is currently logged out: return `true`
- User had never logged in since the browser was opened: **only case** that returns `false`

I'd hate to touch cookies, which is the only solution that I can come up with (still, I don't have much of an idea of how to approach the problem with cookies).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited your question as "previously authenticated" could have meant, to check if a user has ever logged in, which I assume is not what you want, feel free to rollback if I was wrong.

Comment: Um, checking if a user has ever logged in is what I want... no problems, though

Comment: "checking if a user has ever logged in" can mean check if the user ever logged in after making the account. While you want to check if the user is currently logged in, logged in previously with the browser / session, or never logged in with this session, so your question is different than that. Also you might want to rephrase that, you seem to have 3 requirements which can be said to _lack focus_ (A close reason)